# Windows server2003 time not running normally

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

we are currently using a temporary Windows 2003 Server as a domain controller but due to a budget issue we are still waiting for an approval inorder to do a migration to the latest OS server.

We are facing since few days a problem when loggging off the server the time stays at the moment we logged off and wont move forward normally.

I was able to find out an error under the event logs showing this message:

Event Type: Error
Event Source: W32Time
Event Category: None
Event ID: 29
Date:   1/25/2018
Time:   11:00:37 AM
User:   N/A
Computer: SERVER1
Description:
The time provider NtpClient is configured to acquire time from one or more time sources, however none of the sources are currently accessible. No attempt to contact a source will be made for 60 minutes. NtpClient has no source of accurate time.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

I did some research and tried to cmd commands that were resetting the w32tm service but none of them worked. Has anyone a professional suggestion and knows what happened because im sure this is more a software/os problem.

Thank you

Comment: `I did some research and tried to cmd commands that were resetting the w32tm service but none of them worked.` - Gee, knowing exactly what commands you ran would sure be helpful. `I did some stuff but it didn't work` really doesn't give us any useful information.

Comment: I went throgh this blog https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nepapfe/2013/03/01/its-simple-time-configuration-in-active-directory/

I also added one of these time servers listed here 
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~help/networking/ntp.html    with the command  w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:timeserver /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update   but when logging off the time stays there. Clients are also affected by this problem.

Comment: Is this server a virtual machine? If so, what virtualization platform/product are you using?

Comment: Is the server allowed to connect to Internet NTPs? If yes, stop win32tm and use `w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.de.pool.ntp.org,0x1 pool.ntp.org,0x1`(See here: http://www.ugg.li/windows-server-2008-2012-2016-als-ntp-server-via-w32time-konfigurieren/)